# How do I use memmap to reserve memory on boot?

Tags: linux, boot, memory

I have a laptop with some corrupted ram addresses, so I'm trying to use memmap to reserve them before linux boots up.

I have been trying to use `memmap=10M$1024M` as a kernel boot option, but linux crashes (with no errors) and restarts. If I use a different syntax for memmap like `memmap=1023M@0M` it boots fine.

Do I have to specify a certain size block to reserve or could my kernel version not support reserving memory with memmap?

Maybe I'm better off using `memmap=exactmap`, and if so, could somebody point me to a good faq on how to use it?

Answer (score 2):

i stumbled upon this:

http://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/html_node/badram.html#badram

> This command notifies the memory
>   manager that specified regions of RAM
>   ought to be filtered out (usually,
>   because they're damaged). This remains
>   in effect after a payload kernel has
>   been loaded by GRUB, as long as the
>   loaded kernel obtains its memory map
>   f> rom GRUB. Kernels that support this
>   include Linux, GNU Mach, the kernel of
>   FreeBSD and Multiboot kernels in
>   general.

maybe that helps?

Comment: Im currently in a foreign country where its difficult to get any new parts, so Im looking for a fix for the next two months.

Comment: Use memtest86 and set badram parameters....